# c++ program compile error, cant find/access a file

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, dev-c++

error list https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnI89.jpg
whenever i click compile and run in Dev c++ it stops and marks this line with red `$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)` and collect2.exe doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, i didnt add libglu.a and libglut.a in the linker